# Jquery loading dynamic libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am making a script where my jquery loads a jquery plugin with the getScript() method. But for some reason the code that I load only works after my script has ended.

So the procedure:

1. load jquery
2. do the getScript() method and load the plugin.
3. try to use the plugin ($('#test').myPlugin()) but crashes.
4. script ended. try $('#test').myPlugin() in chrome web developer. Works perfectly.

Comment: Does it work after the page has been cached? I'm curious if the issue is that the script isn't fully downloading before attempting to execute.

Comment: It does not work after the page is cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getScript()-method retrieves the script asynchronous, so you have to wait till it has loaded (usually through the success()-method) to call it. I guess you're not doing that.

So try

```
getScript("script").success(function() {
    $('#test').myPlugin();
});
```

Comment: Well I am not doing that indeed. But when I set a timeout of a couple seconds (for testing purposes). It doesn't work either.

Comment: Yeah, that should work. You could check through chrome developer/firebug how long it takes till the script is loaded at least.

Comment: so setTimeout(function() { $('#test').myPlugin(); }, 1000); doesn't work (just fishing whether there might be a different error somewhere, I'm still not sure if a success-function works for your problem).

Comment: I have used another function to set a timeout. But with yours it is working. Thank you. The problem with it is that it is used in a plugin too. So I probably need to load the plugin synchronously to use it directly in my main javascript file ?